# Joomla main page header length maxmizing

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Unable to adjust main page header length of the  Joomla template(v 3.9.1). Tried changing the template.jss but failed. Great to know the correct way of adjusting the main page header length.

Below is the current and expected format. As you can see in "As-is" Downloads menu is appearing in the bottom which suppose to be next to "Contact us" in same line.

As is:

[image]

To be :

[image]

Comment: This looks like a good question to post at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  When you post there, we are going to need to see your actual coding attempt.

Comment: It might also help to mention which template you are using. Often it is easier to reduce the font size to make the menu items fit in one line rather than modifying the width of the header which may not be easy to do without affecting changing the width of the content in the template. You might also be able to amend some of the existing menu items to make room e.g. "About" instead of "About Us" and "Contact" rather than "Contact Us'.

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you . Same post is replicated in Joomla Stack Exchange.

Comment: @NeilRobertson thank you for your feedback. Good idea on amending the existing menu. But font size already small. It would helpful if any idea can apply without changing the font size.

Comment: As I told you in my comment, we are going to need to see your coding attempt(s). Is `template.jss` a hybrid file containing `.js` and `.css` ? ;)